# Proof of (Vi + Vf)/2

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

Its quite intuitive that when you have constant acceleration, the average velocity is given by (Vi + Vf)/2, but how can you prove it?

Comment: $$s=v_i \Delta t +\frac{1}{2}a\Delta t^2$$

$$\bar{v}=\frac{s}{\Delta t}=v_i+\frac{1}{2}a\Delta t$$

$$v_i+v_f=v_i+v_i+at$$
Ok?

Comment: How do you prove any average?

Comment: What is the average of two quantities?

Answer (score 4):

In general, assume you have some time-varying quantity $f(t)$, that varies from some time $t_{0}$ to some other time $t_{f}$.  Now, graph $f(t)$.  There will be some area under this curve.  The average value of $f(t)$ over this time interval, $\bar f$ will be the height of the square that has the same base as the graph of $f(t)$ and the same area as $f(t)$ has under it's curve.

Since the area under a curve is given by $\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}dt\,f(t)$, and the area of the square is given by ${\bar f}\left({t_{f}-t_{0}}\right)$, it's easy enough to figure out that ${\bar f} = \frac{1}{t_{f}-t_{0}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}dt\,f(t)$

But you don't need calculus to figure all of this out for constant acceleration, because, for constant acceleration, the graph of velocity versus time is a straight line.  All we need to know is that the area of the graph is given by a triangle stacked on a square.  The square has height $v_{0}$, and the triangle has height $v_{f} - v_{0}$.  Both have base $t_{f}-t_{0}$
$$\begin{align}A &= \frac{1}{2}bh + b\,v_{0}\\
{\bar v}(t_{f}-t_{0})&= \frac{1}{2}(t_{f}-t_{0})(v_{f}-v_{0}) + v_{0}(t_{f}-t_{0})\\
{\bar v} &=\frac{1}{2}(v_{f}-v_{0}) + v_{0}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(v_{f} + v_{0})
\end{align}$$